# Two ajax actions and one container

Tags: gridview, yii2, pjax

I have following issue: I need to use exactly one pjax container for two different actions.

To be exact, one of them is used for reloading gridview after form submitted. 
The second one is required to fill in form with data of model user'd like to edit.
Even though in the first case script works correctly, the second one causes filling in right form and also replaces gridview to form.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

My code below:

GRIDVIEW

```
<?= GridView::widget([

                            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,
                            'filterModel' => $searchModel2,
                            'filterPosition' => '',
                            'summary' => "<div class=\"summary\">Razem wniosków: {totalCount} <span id='wnioski-suma'></span></div>",
                            'layout' => '{pager}{items}{summary}',
                            'columns' => [
                                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                                'nr_wniosku',
                                //'kwota',
                                [
                                'attribute' => 'kwota',
                                'value' => function($model) {
                                    return Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($model->kwota, "PLN");
                                }
                                ],
                                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                                    'buttons' => [
                                    'usunwniosek' => function ($url, $model) {
                                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                                        //'data-confirm' => 'Czy na pewno usunąć ten rekord?',
                                        'class'=>'btn btn-default btn-xs btn-szeroki',
                                        ]);

                                    },
                                    'edytujwniosek' => function ($url, $model) {
                                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, [
                                        'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                                        'class'=>'btn btn-default btn-xs btn-szeroki gv-btn-edit',
                                        ]);
                                    }
                                ],
                                'template' => '{edytujwniosek} {usunwniosek}',
                                'visible' => $btns,
                    ],
                            ],
                        ]); ?>
```

js for creating new record:

```
$pjaxjs = '
   $("document").ready(function(){ 
        $("#new_wniosek").on("pjax:end", function() {
            console.log("pjax on new_wniosek end");
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#wnioski-lista"});  //Reload GridView
        });
    });
    ';

    $this->registerJs($pjaxjs, $this::POS_READY);
```

js for editing record:

```
$("document").ready(function(){ 

    $(document).on("click", "a.gv-btn-edit", function(event) {

        $.pjax.reload({container:"#new_wniosek"});  //Reload GridView
  });
    });
```

**Any suggestions, please?**

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @arogachev Right, I've attached code to my post.

Comment: Pjax is a simple library, but it should do what you want without writing any JS code, are you sure you are not complicating it without reason? You have a link, you click on it, pjax takes care of the rest because the links are handled through it.

Comment: @MihaiP. Without any JS, the gridview container is replaced with form, and I'd like to change it, but don't know what way.